# Amazon FBA order report delay

Tags: amazon-mws

To retrieve FBA orders, I use the `_GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_` report. But I'm missing orders regularly.

The Amazon MWS documentation mentions this:

> Note: In Japan, EU, and NA, in most cases, there will be a delay of
>   approximately one to three hours from the time a fulfillment order
>   ships and the time the items in the fulfillment order appear in the
>   report. In some rare cases there could be a delay of up to 24 hours.

When an order appears 24 hours later, then I have processed that time frame already. My way of fetching data is grabbing data from the API every hour, and I do it gapless to not miss anything.

But if an order appears in a "previous" interval, I definitely will miss it. Is that what Amazon is doing? Can't find any resources on it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Your "note" answers your question.

The timeframe you are pulling is the timeframe of when the order showed up on the report, not when it shipped. So even if it shipped 24 hours ago, the report is showing you things that showed up on the report in your timeframe, not things that shipped in your timeframe.

EDIT: additional info. There are 4 dates it gives you. purchaseddate, paymentsdate, shipmentdate and reportingdate. The timeframe in your report request or schedule is based on the reporting date.